# Icon Site actions in custom master page Sharepoint 2013

Tags: master-page

I want to add a Site Actions icon to my custom master page in SharePoint 2013

In my HTML code : I put the tag ( `class="ms-siteactions-root" id="siteactiontd"` ) (iIfound it with firebug, I already added the ms-help without a problem) and in design manager I have the following error :

> ie : is an undeclared prefix

here is the code that I added :

```
<span class="ms-siteactions-root" id="siteactiontd">

<span style="display:none"><menu type="ServerMenu" id="zz9_SiteActionsMenuMain" hideicons="true"><ie:menuitem id="zz10_MenuItem_ShareThisSite" type="option" onmenuclick="EnsureScriptFunc('sharing.js', 'DisplaySharedWithDialog', function () { DisplaySharedWithDialog('\u002f'); })" text="Shared with..." description="See who's here and invite new people." menugroupid="100" enabled="true" checked="false" onmenuclick_original="EnsureScriptFunc('sharing.js', 'DisplaySharedWithDialog', function () { DisplaySharedWithDialog('\u002f'); })" text_original="Shared with..." description_original="See who's here and invite new people." valorig="
"></ie:menuitem>
<ie:menuitem id="zz11_MenuItem_CreatePage" type="option" iconsrc="/_layouts/15/images/NewContentPageHH.png?rev=23" onmenuclick="OpenCreateWebPageDialog('\u002f_layouts\u002f15\u002fcreatewebpage.aspx')" text="Add a page" description="Create a page you can customize." menugroupid="200" enabled="true" checked="false" onmenuclick_original="OpenCreateWebPageDialog('\u002f_layouts\u002f15\u002fcreatewebpage.aspx')" text_original="Add a page" description_original="Create a page you can customize." valorig="
"></ie:menuitem>
<ie:menuitem id="zz12_MenuItem_Create" type="option" onmenuclick="GoToPage('\u002f_layouts\u002f15\u002faddanapp.aspx')" text="Add an app" description="Create other types of pages, lists, libraries, and sites." menugroupid="200" enabled="true" checked="false" onmenuclick_original="GoToPage('\u002f_layouts\u002f15\u002faddanapp.aspx')" text_original="Add an app" description_original="Create other types of pages, lists, libraries, and sites." valorig="
"></ie:menuitem>
<ie:menuitem id="zz13_MenuItem_ViewAllSiteContents" type="option" iconsrc="/_layouts/15/images/allcontent32.png?rev=23" onmenuclick="STSNavigate2(event,'/_layouts/15/viewlsts.aspx');" text="Site contents" description="View all libraries and lists in this site." menugroupid="200" enabled="true" checked="false" onmenuclick_original="STSNavigate2(event,'/_layouts/15/viewlsts.aspx');" text_original="Site contents" description_original="View all libraries and lists in this site." valorig="
"></ie:menuitem>
<ie:menuitem id="ctl00_ctl00_ctl53_SiteActionsMenuMain_ctl00_wsaDesignEditor" type="option" iconsrc="/_layouts/15/images/designer.png?rev=23" onmenuclick="STSNavigate2(event,'/_layouts/15/DesignSite.aspx');" text="Design Manager" description="Change the look and feel of this site." menugroupid="300" enabled="true" checked="false" onmenuclick_original="STSNavigate2(event,'/_layouts/15/DesignSite.aspx');" text_original="Design Manager" description_original="Change the look and feel of this site." valorig="
"></ie:menuitem>
<ie:menuitem id="zz14_MenuItem_Settings" type="option" iconsrc="/_layouts/15/images/settingsIcon.png?rev=23" onmenuclick="GoToPage('\u002f_layouts\u002f15\u002fsettings.aspx')" text="Site settings" description="Access all settings for this site." menugroupid="300" enabled="true" checked="false" onmenuclick_original="GoToPage('\u002f_layouts\u002f15\u002fsettings.aspx')" text_original="Site settings" description_original="Access all settings for this site." valorig="
"></ie:menuitem>
<ie:menuitem id="ctl00_ctl00_ctl53_SiteActionsMenuMain_ctl00_ctl02" type="option" onmenuclick="STSNavigate2(event,'/GettingStarted.aspx');" text="Getting started" description="Get started with your site." menugroupid="2147483647" enabled="true" checked="false" onmenuclick_original="STSNavigate2(event,'/GettingStarted.aspx');" text_original="Getting started" description_original="Get started with your site." valorig="
"></ie:menuitem>
</menu></span><span id="zz15_SiteActionsMenu_t" class="ms-siteactions-normal" title="Settings" onmouseover="MMU_PopMenuIfShowing(this);MMU_EcbTableMouseOverOut(this, true)" hoveractive="ms-siteactions-normal ms-siteactions-hover" hoverinactive="ms-siteactions-normal" onclick=" CoreInvoke('MMU_Open',byid('zz9_SiteActionsMenuMain'), MMU_GetMenuFromClientId('zz15_SiteActionsMenu'),event,true, null, 0); return false;" foa="MMU_GetMenuFromClientId('zz15_SiteActionsMenu')" oncontextmenu="ClkElmt(this); return false;"><a class="ms-core-menu-root" id="zz15_SiteActionsMenu" accesskey="/" href="javascript:;" title="Settings" onkeydown="MMU_EcbLinkOnKeyDown(byid('zz9_SiteActionsMenuMain'), MMU_GetMenuFromClientId('zz15_SiteActionsMenu'));" menutokenvalues="MENUCLIENTID=zz15_SiteActionsMenu,TEMPLATECLIENTID=zz9_SiteActionsMenuMain" serverclientid="zz15_SiteActionsMenu"><span class="ms-siteactions-imgspan"><img class="ms-core-menu-buttonIcon" src="/_layouts/15/images/spcommon.png?rev=23" alt="Settings" title="Settings"></span><span class="ms-accessible">Use SHIFT+ENTER to open the menu (new window).</span></a></span></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

it should be within the masterpage, and not the rendered html but rather aspx ;)

```
        <SharePoint:AjaxDelta runat="server" id="DeltaSuiteBarRight" CssClass="ms-core-deltaSuiteBarRight" BlockElement="true">
            <SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl runat="server" AuthenticationRestrictions="AuthenticatedUsersOnly" EmitDiv="true">
                <div id="welcomeMenuBox">
  <wssuc:Welcome id="IdWelcome" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" />
                </div>
                <div id="suiteBarButtons">
                       <span class="ms-siteactions-root" id="siteactiontd">
                       <SharePoint:SiteActions runat="server" accesskey="<%$Resources:wss,tb_SiteActions_AK%>" id="SiteActionsMenuMain"
                        PrefixHtml=""
                        SuffixHtml=""
                        ImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/spcommon.png?rev=23"
                        ThemeKey="spcommon"
                        MenuAlignment="Right"
                        MenuNotVisibleHtml="&amp;nbsp;"
                        LargeIconMode="false"
                        >
                        <CustomTemplate>
                        <SharePoint:FeatureMenuTemplate runat="server"
                            FeatureScope="Site"
                            Location="Microsoft.SharePoint.StandardMenu"
                            GroupId="SiteActions"
                            UseShortId="true"
                            >
                          <SharePoint:MenuItemTemplate runat="server"
                              id="MenuItem_ShareThisSite"
                              Text="<%$Resources:wss,siteactions_sharethissite%>"
                              Description="<%$Resources:wss,siteactions_sharethissitedescription%>"
                              MenuGroupId="100"
                              Sequence="110"
                              UseShortId="true"
                              PermissionsString="ViewPages"
                              PermissionMode="Any" />
                          <SharePoint:MenuItemTemplate runat="server" id="MenuItem_EditPage"
                              Text="<%$Resources:wss,siteactions_editpage15%>"
                              Description="<%$Resources:wss,siteactions_editpagedescriptionv4%>"
                              ImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/ActionsEditPage.png?rev=23"
                              MenuGroupId="200"
                              Sequence="210"
                              PermissionsString="EditListItems"
                              ClientOnClickNavigateUrl="javascript:ChangeLayoutMode(false);" />
                          <SharePoint:MenuItemTemplate runat="server" id="MenuItem_CreatePage"
                              Text="<%$Resources:wss,siteactions_addpage15%>"
                              Description="<%$Resources:wss,siteactions_createpagedesc%>"
                              ImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/NewContentPageHH.png?rev=23"
                              MenuGroupId="200"
                              Sequence="220"
                              UseShortId="true"
                              ClientOnClickScriptContainingPrefixedUrl="OpenCreateWebPageDialog('~siteLayouts/createwebpage.aspx')"
                              PermissionsString="AddListItems, EditListItems"
                              PermissionMode="All" />
                          <SharePoint:MenuItemTemplate runat="server" id="MenuItem_Create"
                              Text="<%$Resources:wss,siteactions_addapp15%>"
                              Description="<%$Resources:wss,siteactions_createdesc%>"
                              MenuGroupId="200"
                              Sequence="230"
                              UseShortId="true"
                              ClientOnClickScriptContainingPrefixedUrl="GoToPage('~siteLayouts/addanapp.aspx')"
                              PermissionsString="ManageLists, ManageSubwebs"
                              PermissionMode="Any" />
                          <SharePoint:MenuItemTemplate runat="server" id="MenuItem_ViewAllSiteContents"
                              Text="<%$Resources:wss,quiklnch_allcontent_15%>"
                              Description="<%$Resources:wss,siteactions_allcontentdescription%>"
                              ImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/allcontent32.png?rev=23"
                              MenuGroupId="200"
                              Sequence="240"
                              UseShortId="true"
                              ClientOnClickNavigateUrl="~siteLayouts/viewlsts.aspx"
                              PermissionsString="ViewFormPages"
                              PermissionMode="Any" />
                          <SharePoint:MenuItemTemplate runat="server" id="MenuItem_ChangeTheLook"
                              Text="<%$Resources:wss,siteactions_changethelook15%>"
                              Description="<%$Resources:wss,siteactions_changethelookdesc15%>"
                              MenuGroupId="300"
                              Sequence="310"
                              UseShortId="true"
                              ClientOnClickNavigateUrl="~siteLayouts/designgallery.aspx"
                              PermissionsString="ApplyThemeAndBorder,ApplyStyleSheets,Open,ViewPages,OpenItems,ViewListItems"
                              PermissionMode="All" />
                          <SharePoint:MenuItemTemplate runat="server" id="MenuItem_Settings"
                              Text="<%$Resources:wss,siteactions_settings15%>"
                              Description="<%$Resources:wss,siteactions_sitesettingsdescriptionv4%>"
                              ImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/settingsIcon.png?rev=23"
                              MenuGroupId="300"
                              Sequence="320"
                              UseShortId="true"
                              ClientOnClickScriptContainingPrefixedUrl="GoToPage('~siteLayouts/settings.aspx')"
                              PermissionsString="EnumeratePermissions,ManageWeb,ManageSubwebs,AddAndCustomizePages,ApplyThemeAndBorder,ManageAlerts,ManageLists,ViewUsageData"
                              PermissionMode="Any" />
                          <SharePoint:MenuItemTemplate runat="server" id="MenuItem_SwitchToMobileView"
                              Visible="false"
                              Text="<%$Resources:wss,siteactions_switchtomobileview%>"
                              Description="<%$Resources:wss,siteactions_switchtomobileviewdesc%>"
                              MenuGroupId="300"
                              Sequence="330"
                              UseShortId="true"
                              ClientOnClickScript="var mswlh = window.location.href; if (mswlh.indexOf('?')==-1) { window.location = mswlh + '?mobile=1'; } else { window.location = mswlh + '&mobile=1'; }" />
                        </SharePoint:FeatureMenuTemplate>
                        </CustomTemplate>
                      </SharePoint:SiteActions></span>
                    <span id="ms-help">
                        <SharePoint:ThemedClusteredHoverImage
                            runat="server"
                            ID="TopHelpLink"
                            ThemeKey="spintl"
                            TouchMode="true"
                            TouchModeWidth="30"
                            TouchModeHeight="30"
                            TouchModePaddingTop="7"
                            TouchModePaddingRight="7"
                            TouchModePaddingBottom="7"
                            TouchModePaddingLeft="7"
                            ImageUrl="/_layouts/15/~lcid/images/spintl.png"
                            Width="16"
                            Height="16"
                            OffsetX="19"
                            OffsetY="1"
                            HoverOffsetX="1"
                            HoverOffsetY="1"
                            NavigateUrl="#"
                            onclick="TopHelpButtonClick('HelpHome',event);return false"
                            AlternateText="<%$Resources:wss,multipages_helplink_text%>"
                            AccessKey="<%$Resources:wss,multipages_helplink_accesskey%>"
                            ToolTip="<%$Resources:wss,multipages_helplink_text%>" />
                    </span>
                </div>
            </SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>
        </SharePoint:AjaxDelta>
```

Comment: I tried your exp, in my .master but nothing changes in my HTML or in Design manager (i mapped the driver so i have .html and .master files)

Comment: When I close and reopen the .master afteradding the code, I don't find what I added it's deleted

Comment: are you: downloading to local hdd, open up .master, makes changes, within /_catalogs/masterpage/Forms/AllItems.aspx upload the file, check in the new uploaded version and publish major version.... or are you doing it through spd?

Comment: when I want to save there's a warning msg :   the master page does not have any content regions defined, do you want to save anyway ? when I hit Yes and reopen the file, I don't find the code

Comment: ok, means you dont have any contentplaceholders within your masterpage? is your masterpage custom? can you show it here by ammending your question?

Comment: I have custom master page and I have placeholders, how can I send you my .master and .html files ??

Comment: just copy the code and edit your question, pasting in the code into your question!

Comment: I can't but you can DL the 2 files from this link :                     http://www.grosfichiers.ch/en/x75XPGpVxUcbg3yfWbsLotNI

Comment: ok, will look at them but at the moment i cant as i cant download at work :(

Comment: If you have modified your master page it will be stored in the content database not the file system, are you sure you are editing the correct file?

Comment: Yes I am because I mapped my network so when I save a file, it s stored in the content DB . PS : I found a solution : juste changed ie:menuitem by menuitem and it works

Answer (score 0):

I used JS to solve this, however it won't let me remove or hide the "Add an app" link.

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function () {
  var items = document.getElementByTagName('ie:menuitem');
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        var item = items[i];
        if(item.id.match('CreatePage') != null) {
            item.hidden = true;
            item.parentNode.removeChild(item);
        }
    }
});
```